# sending MQTT messages from a webpage written in python with Flask

Tags: python, flask, mqtt, iot, paho

I am trying to send a MQTT message from a web page built using Flask.

I have established the connection in the main loop and I am able to send a message before starting Flask

When i call:

```
client.publish('all/camera/'+path, 'all')
```

nothing happens. No error but no message is sent. My best guess is that this is a scope problem. ie. that the object 'client' is not visible to the function. I have tried to initiate the client outside of the main function and i have also tried to declare 'client' as global inside the capture() function

the code for the flask app is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def capture():
    timestring=datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    if 'sessionName' in request.form:
        sessionName = request.form['sessionName']
        path = sessionName + "_" + timestring
        return render_template ('capture.html', path=path, timestring=timestring, sessionName=sessionName)
        client.publish('all/camera/'+path, 'all')
    else:
        return render_template ('capture.html',timestring=timestring)


# paho callbacks

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):

    #sub here will re subscribe on reconnection
    client.subscribe("+/camera/#")
    client.subscribe("+/led")



# Main Code


if __name__=='__main__':

    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect("scanserver.local",1883,60)
    client.loop_start()
    client.publish('debug', 'server running')

    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0' , debug = True, port=5001)
```

Comment: you should call client.publish before return

Answer (score 0):

As rmn said. I had put the return in the wrong place. Working perfectly now. Thanks